# Making a currency converter for a project, I am using .map over the strings however EUR is coming up as a duplicate saying it needs a unique key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react'

export default function CurrencyRow(props) {
    const {
        currencyOptions
    } = props
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="number" className="input-box" />
            <select>
                {currencyOptions.map(option => (
                    <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `currentOptions` ? Your problem doesn't seem to come from your code here.

Comment: The value of currencyOptions is an array of currencies however, EUR appears twice once at the start as it is the base currency and once in the middle as it would appear alphabetically.

Comment: function App() {
  const [currencyOptions, setCurrencyOptions] = useState([])
  console.log(currencyOptions)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(BASE_URL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      setCurrencyOptions([data.base, ...Object.keys(data.rates)])
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
    <h1>Convert</h1>
    <CurrencyRow 
    currencyOptions={currencyOptions}
    />
    <div className="equals">=</div>
    <CurrencyRow 
    currencyOptions={currencyOptions}
    />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Answer (score 0):

The key must always be unique for each element and Since the key is repeating in the array `currencyOptions` the errors shows up.

To avoid this error you can try it this way

```
array.map((element, index) => { /* ... */ })
```

You can read more about it at : [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
since the index is unique for each element you can use

```
currencyOptions.map(option,index => (
                    <option key={index} value={option}>{option}</option>
                ))
```

Comment: I then get an error which says 'option is not defined'

Comment: Can you just copy-paste the exact `currencyOptions` Array

Comment: The array is too long to copy here, I could have a work around where I just remove the 47th element from it as it is 'EUR' which is the duplicate. I have tried .splice() but I am pretty new to javascript and having some problems

Comment: I managed to delete the 47th element which was the duplicate giving me issues

Comment: I Got the solution it's showing you option is not defined as you have never imported it `currencyOptions.map(element,index => (
                    <option key={index} value={element}>{element}</option>
                ))`

Comment: You used `<option></option> but I don't think you imported it and my personal advice is never to use the same variable name